# Oracle sapling of data in parallel

Tags: sql, oracle

I have X million records in a table `TABLE_A` and want to process these records one by one.
How can I divide the population equally among 10 instances of same PL/SQL scripts to process in parallel?

See below query

```
SELECT CBR.CUSTOMER_ID, CBR.NAME, CBR.DEPT_NAME
FROM
(
    SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, NAME, HOME_TELNO, DEPT_NAME, ROWNUM AS RNUM
    FROM TABLE_A ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID ASC
) CBR
WHERE CBR.RNUM < :sqli_end_rownum AND CBR.RNUM >= :sqli_start_rownum ;
```

Values will be incremented in each iteration of loop. In next iteration `sqli_start_rownum` will become `sqli_end_rownum`.

This query is taking much time. Does someone has better way to do it

Comment: What are you trying to achieve processing one by one? Can't it get done in a single query?

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: There are other things which I will be doing. Involving different tables.
I am using 11g

Comment: If I remember correctly `rownum` gets executed before `order by` so it may happen you get different row numbers on every execution. Sometimes when I want to work on separate blocks of data, I use the modulo function, e.g. `select * from tablea where mod(customer_id, 10) = 0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look into DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_parallel_ex.htm#ARPLS67331

For example:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/dbms_parallel_execute_11gR2

The poor man's version of this is basically to run a query to generate ranges of rowids. You can then access the rows in the table within a given range.

Step1: create the number of "buckets" you want to divide the table into and get a range of rowids for each bucket. Here's an 8-bucket example:

```
select bucket_num, min(rid) as start_rowid, max(rid) as end_rowid, count(*)
  from (select rowid rid
             , ntile(8) over (order by rowid) as bucket_num
          from table_a
) 
group by bucket_num
order by bucket_num;
```

You'd get an output that looks like this (I'm using 12c - rowids may look different in 11g):

```
BUCKET_NUM  START_ROWID         END_ROWID           COUNT(*)
1           AABetTAAIAAB8GCAAA  AABetTAAIAAB8u5AAl  82792
2           AABetTAAIAAB8u5AAm  AABetTAAIAAB9RrABi  82792
3           AABetTAAIAAB9RrABj  AABetTAAIAAB96vAAU  82792
4           AABetTAAIAAB96vAAV  AABetTAAIAAB+gKAAs  82792
5           AABetTAAIAAB+gKAAt  AABetTAAIAAB+/vABv  82792
6           AABetTAAIAAB+/vABw  AABetTAAIAAB/hbAB1  82791
7           AABetTAAIAAB/hbAB2  AABetTAAIAACARDABf  82791
8           AABetTAAIAACARDABg  AABetTAAIAACBGnABq  82791
```

(The sum of the counts will be the total number of rows in the table at the time of the query.)

Step2: can grab a set of rows from the table for a given range:

```
SELECT <whatever you need>
  FROM <table>
 WHERE rowid BETWEEN 'AABetTAAIAAB8GCAAA' and 'AABetTAAIAAB8u5AAl'
...
```

Step3: repeat step2 for the given ranges.

so instead of this:

```
SELECT CBR.CUSTOMER_ID, CBR.NAME, CBR.DEPT_NAME
FROM
(
    SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, NAME, HOME_TELNO, DEPT_NAME, ROWNUM AS RNUM
    FROM TABLE_A ORDER BY CUSTOMER_ID ASC
) CBR
WHERE CBR.RNUM < :sqli_end_rownum AND CBR.RNUM >= :sqli_start_rownum ;
```

you'll just have this:

```
SELECT CBR.CUSTOMER_ID, CBR.NAME, CBR.DEPT_NAME
  FROM table_a
 WHERE rowid BETWEEN :start_rowid and :end_rowid
```

You can use this to run the same job in parallel but you'll need a separate session for each run (e.g. multiple SQL Plus sessions. You can also use something like DBMS_JOBS/DBMS_SCHEDULER to launch background jobs.

(Note: always be aware if your table is being updated between the time the buckets are calculated and the time you access the tables as you can miss rows.)

Comment: Basically my JOB is in C. I will use your suggested new query in a cursor in Pro*C.
Although this one is fast but showing more cost in explain plan. If possible can you explain why So

Comment: Cost is an estimate based on several factors and if something as simple as table statistics are off, you can get a meaningless number. Another factor is the row estimates: often times Oracle can't tell how many rows will be returned from a particular WHERE clause and again, the cost may not be representative of how much work will *actually* be done when the data is processed. Remember that cost is used to generate a plan, that's it. Since it's the execution plan that matters at query time, try and understand if the order of operations makes sense.

Comment: Your solution really helped me a lot. Now I need to solve similar problem but this time with two more constraint.
1) Consider only X number of records of table_a
2) There is one more column in table_a, P1 VARCHR2(10). It has two value, either 0 or 1. So while selecting the ranges records with value 0 should be considered first.

I think rowid approach will not work in this case as last rowid could have the value 0 and if so, it should be selected first.

Do you know any such fast solution for this as well?

Comment: The rowid approach assumes you're looking at considering all of the rows for update. If you're skipping rows, obviously you can't use "between rowidX and rowidY." Is relocating rows to another table an option or do all the rows (candidate rows and rows you wish to ignore) need to be in the same table while the update is happening?